# добавление в массив Python

Tags: python, массивы

у меня в Python есть такой массив:

```
a = [[], [], [], [], []]
```

мне нужно получить такой:

```
[[[1, 2, 3]], [], [], [], []]
```

если я делаю `a[0].append([1,2,3])`, то получаю `[[[1,2,3]], [[1,2,3]], [[1,2,3]], [[1,2,3]], [[1,2,3]]]`

Просто `a[0] = [1, 2, 3]` не подходит, т.к. после мне нужно будет еще добавлять элементы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы нас обманываете, с таким массивом такое быть не может, у вас какой-то другой массив. Приведите полный и настоящий код, который демонстрирует проблему

Comment: Вы нас всё ещё обманываете, если что

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо большое! Помогло :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[]] * 5  # создаст пять ссылок на один и тот же пустой список
print(a)  # [[], [], [], [], []] - id всех элементов будут равны
id(a[0]) == id(a[1]) == id(a[2]) == id(a[3]) == id(a[4])  # True
# Соответсвенно, изменение любого списка будет затрагивать и все остальные
a[0].append([1, 2, 3])  # [[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]]


a = [[] for _ in range(5)]  # создаст пять новых пустых списков
a[0].append([1, 2, 3])  # [[[1, 2, 3]], [], [], [], []]
```